# Dynamic PHP Variables not working with codeigniter php view file using mPDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, mpdf, codeigniter-3

```
//code in my controller

//get users data
$users = $this->users->get_users();
$data['users'] = $users;

//fetch view fro pdf_output.php view file
$html=$this->load->view('pdf_output', $data,TRUE);

//load mPDF library
$this->load->library('m_pdf');

//write content using pdf library
$this->pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$this->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "I");

//code in my view file
print_r($data);exit;
```

I am unable to access the $data variable in "pdf_output.php" view file in codeigniter 3.0. I am getting an error like "Message: Undefined variable: data".

Please post the answer if anyone have.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `$users` instead of `$data` in the view? Otherwise you need to set `$data['data']['users']=...`

Comment: Whats the value of `$users` before assigning it to `$data['users']` ?

Comment: $users contains an array of result fetched from database using sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view file the variable will be $users instead of $data.

if you have an array like this for example

```
  $data['users'] = array("user1","user2");
  $this->load->view('viewpage', $data);
```

in your view file it will be $users;

```
 print_r($users);
```